# Go convert reflect.Value from string to int

Tags: reflection, go

I am getting an error like this

```
reflect.Value.Convert: value of type string cannot be converted to type int
goroutine 6
```

When I am running this code

```
param := "1" // type string
ps := fn.In(i) // type int

if !reflect.TypeOf(param).ConvertibleTo(ps) {
    fmt.Print("Could not convert parameter.\n") // this is printed
}
convertedParam := reflect.ValueOf(param).Convert(ps)
```

Can I do this in some way without creating a switch/case and multiple lines of code for converting to each type?
I am just looking for the easiest/best way to do this.

Comment: A switch is required if you don't know what type the thing is going to be and want to decide how to handle it at runtime. This is fundamentally unavoidable. That being said, your question confuses me because the thing you want to convert just can't. The only strings that you can convert to ints are numerical ones like `"24"` and the familiar methods from C are provided in the package JimB suggested using.

Comment: I updated the question, it is a numerical string, is it possible then?

Comment: It is. I recommend using `strconv` rather than `reflect`. You probably just want to do `myInt, err := strconv.ParseInt(param, 10, 64)` and then check the error. If the string was not a numerical value, `err` will be non-nil, if it was then `myInt` will hold that value. At least if you're expecting the input to be a numerical string. This isn't a good approach for handling any input, that will still require a switch statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are specific rules for [type conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions). Strings cannot be converted to numeric values.

Use the [`strconv`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/) package to read a numeric value from a string.

Comment: This is the right answer. In addition if you want to see what conversions are available take a look at the `Convert()` function implementation: `https://golang.org/src/reflect/value.go?s=63892:63928#L2164`

Answer (score 0):

You can use switch in loop through the reflect values which will return the reflect.Value kind() to return the exact type of that value

```
v := reflect.ValueOf(s interface{})
for t := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
fmt.Println(v.Field(i)) // it will prints the value at index in interface
switch t := v.Kind() {
    case bool:
        fmt.Printf("boolean %t\n", t) // t has type bool
    case int:
        fmt.Printf("integer %d\n", t) // t has type int
    case *bool:
        fmt.Printf("pointer to boolean %t\n", *t) // t has type *bool
    case *int:
        fmt.Printf("pointer to integer %d\n", *t) // t has type *int
    default:
        fmt.Printf("unexpected type %T\n", t) // %T prints whatever type t has
    }
}
```

To convert a type in interface to another type first fetch the value of it in a variable and then use type conversions to convert the value